# how to query oracle database in SQL linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I linked ORACLE Database in my local sql server called X.

**ORACLE database** : Y

**ORACLE table name** : PS.PSDBOWNER

**SQL SERVER Name**: X

I tried below query in my `SSMS`

```
select * from [X].[Y].[PS].[PSDBOWNER]
```

But its not working, Please let me know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

for those who is still looking for an answer to this question, that is to query oracle linked server in sql server, use a select statement like this:

```
select * from [oracle-linked-server-name]..[oracle-table-owner].[oracle-table-name]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM X.Y.dbo.[PS.PSDBOWNER]
```